# Setting Radio Button Value (more than one word/contains spaces) with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a quiz that uses radio buttons to let the user select their answer. I'd like to set the value of the radio buttons to the answer (i.e. Q: "What's the capital of Spain?" radio button value: "Madrid"). I have no problem doing this when the answer is a number or a one-word string, but strings with spaces only return the first word of the string as the radio button's value.

The answers are stored in an array and I'm iterating through it to populate the quiz choices.

```
for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
            var radio = $('<input type="radio" value=' + answers[j] + ' name="choice" />');
            $("#As").append(radio).append(answers[j]).append("<br />");
        }
```

The problem is that when checking to see if the user's answer is right, I'm comparing the value of the radio button they checked with the actual answer. For multiple word answers, the user selected value comes in as "firstword" while the answer might be "firstword secondword thirdword". These aren't equal and the user unfairly misses a point.

I've worked around this by simply setting the radio button's value to j and then later comparing answers[j] to the correct answer (works great), but is there any way to directly set the radio button's value to a string that contains spaces, or is there any other way one might implement this better? Is it not good practice for a radio button's value to be a multi-word string? I couldn't find it explicitly stated that a value couldn't contain spaces but that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this is because you forgot to put quotes out side of the value you put. Please try this

```
for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
   var radio = $('<input type="radio" value="' + answers[j] + '" name="choice" />');
   $("#As").append(radio).append(answers[j]).append("<br />");
}
```

Comment: ahhhh I can't believe it. So simple. Thanks!